# Is it possible to trigger a local notification after an event IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uilocalnotification

Im working on an app that does some computationally heavy tasks that take a long time. I want to notify the user with a local push notification when the task is done. Is this possible? The only information I have been able to find online is to do with triggering notifications at certain times/dates or if the app has entered the background or terminated, all of which is done in the appDelegate. Is there a way to do this in my own classes?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean local notifications or push notifications? The title is a little misleading

Comment: The reason I ask is that local notifications will appear like push notifications when your app is in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain you're looking for a `UILocalNotification` example because the post title mentions push notifications. Either way, you can schedule local notifications from any class you want

```
- (void)throwLocalNotificationWithMessage:(NSString*)message {    
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    localNotification.fireDate = now;
    localNotification.alertBody = message;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber++;
}
```

Also, for my needs I throw these local notifications when region monitoring detects boundary enter/exit changes. This code runs while my app is in the background, as well, and in that case they appear like push notifications.

Comment: Sorry I didnt realise I left push in the title, I was on a straight 10 hour coding binge and was a little tired. This is exactly what I was looking for though, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The above answer by Aaron works fine but don't forget to ask permission for Local Notification. In my case case I ask permission at `AppDelegate` under -

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

and here is the code for iOS8 and iOS9

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
```